# Equivalent of git add --patch with two local files

Tags: git, merge, diff, patch

I have two versions of a long configuration file that have diverged (edited by different users).  I want to reconcile them into one file that includes the best of both existing versions.

I know there are dedicated tools for tasks like these (e.g., vimdiff), but I'm used to the workflow of `git add --patch` for interactive selection of what to include in a reconciled file.

Is there a way to use the `git add --patch` tooling to combine two files that aren't in git?

Comment: No. Use another tool like kdiff3.

Comment: I agree... it would only make sense to use git add if the files were in git.  If not, there are dedicated tools like kDiff or BeyondCompare that do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not eager to use a diff tool like meld, then you can use your familiar flow by copying the files into a new repository.

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
git init
cp /path/to/config1 ./config
git add .
git commit -m "first config"
cp /path/to/config2 ./config
git add -p
git commit -m "merged second config"
cp config /path/to/config/
```